# TypeScript function overloading problem in return types

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, return

Could you explain why the function `funcOverloadingFail` doesn't work within TypeScript syntax?
Function overloading was used in the following examples.

`funcOverloading` and `funcOverloadingFail` functions return the same types(string and boolean),
but do this in different ways.

```
function funcOverloading(member: number): boolean;
function funcOverloading(member: string): string;
function funcOverloading(member: number | string) {
  if (typeof member === 'number') {
    return member > 3;
  } else { 
    return member;
  }
}


function funcOverloadingFail(member: number): boolean;
function funcOverloadingFail(member: string): string;
function funcOverloadingFail(member: number | string) {
  if (typeof member === 'number') {
    return true;  // Error here
  } else { 
    return "3";  // Error here
  }
}
```

On the other hand TypeScript allows to do the same without a function overloading.

```
function funcBoolean(member: number): boolean {
  return true;
}

function funcString(member: string): string {
  return "example";
}
```

However it can be fixed by adding explicitly the union of return types: `string | boolean`

```
function funcOverloadingFixed(member: number): boolean;
function funcOverloadingFixed(member: string): string;
function funcOverloadingFixed(member: number | string): string | boolean {
  if (typeof member === 'number') {
    return true;
  } else { 
    return "example";
  }
}
```

TypeScript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEFcDsGMBcCWB7apkDcCmAnANsgIYAmi0A5qAO6EDOoktWxoZoAZsngVWZVgA9CAWwAOeLLQBQIDjADy2fEVIVQhaC3YKlBEn3CFEeOXCSp6OLPEg408ABZZQtEc-gBPUZIAUteDh86pqgAEbIXFgaAJQANKAyYKGQ8KDEyKCOiPRspOzsuFjQqTQe0omgAMLIkHgsHjWgguJGaFQOHplOpggoaNrQirh6quSGxmnIktAA5CXIOADW1IhZaAAqXlgAyrCBoqm0HsWEAgD8UlIDvag9Q8r6FD7CWMKhuABcoNCQb7jRX3CkQ0AG4rjAbv0IfcRnxnq93jgvv5AhQAS4AnwwddzFC4DCVHCXn8kd9fojQAAfDGo8jRUAAbykoFY7FAPk83mQbOJFIAvALQDMfiSZvSmSyWVYbHZQLzcKAAHygADMYJZAF8mngmIyEpLQNLbGh5Th1aANVJLeCzH07rpCRRxnh4SSviLEeigRJQTbIfbho6xkYXabkZi0eHadiIbiAw9Rs7XYj3eSFdSUXxxczWezOVhuXKEQqBXyhR7cGLGTmpdZjZkcJAsOatVgdc4GfrJUbZQAiQQicRYXstq2XP1x64AIQiPugyc+ZJJXtnUTQEsNddlASbYOtOLt122EfIC9JmcjNKCG57aH7QjEEhHY8uB9u1wJjzGiAEzDPqeXQFV19N88VgT9Ex-P8wyvS8L3IGNbXfaEHS-cAoOIf8lwpDMT3ReCqTCYD1xzRA2Q5LZC1NUBS3LNMcCrDdaxlexG2bHNW3bPUa03FjQHvQcn1HDUgA)

Comment: The implementation of `funcOverloadingFail` doesn't return `boolean` and `string` - it returns `true` (a type whose only value is `true`) and `'3'` (a type whose only value is `'3'`). Therefore, it's narrower than the overload declarations, which is not allowed.

Comment: I had the same thoughts(that i return literal type, e.g. "3" instead of string), but it works with regular functions.